# What happens if the slave(reader instance) is down with typeorm Replication,Using aws aurora (postgresql)

Tags: nestjs, amazon-rds, typeorm, amazon-aurora

---

```
{
  type: "mysql",
  logging: true,
  replication: {
    master: {
      host: "database-2-instance1",
      port: 3306,
      username: "test",
      password: "test",
      database: "test"
    },
    slaves: [{
      host: "database-2-instance1-eu-west-1b",
      port: 3306,
      username: "test",
      password: "test",
      database: "test"
    }]
  }
}
```

---

I would like to setup my nestjs application to use AWS aurora writer and reader  instance with typeorm replication to handle all the read and write queries separately.Aurora config something similar to above

We are using the current setup in RDS.I have a doubt about the time when the reader instance is down/failed.How typeorm handles , does it redirect all the read requests to writer/master instance?

[image]